# Multiple footnotes in minipage - how to typeset as paragraph?

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, minipage

I have a table in a `minipage` with multiple, short footnotes. These are typeset one per line. However, I would like to have these in 'paragraph' mode to save space. I have tried `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` but it does not seem to do anything. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace{-2pt}}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{My caption}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        A & B \\
        \midrule
        test\footnote[1]{note1} & text \\
        test\footnote[2]{note2} & text\footnote[3]{note3} \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use package `threeparttablex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{ccl}
      foo\tnote{a} & bar\tnote{b} & baz and so on with text in this column\\
      foobar       & barfoo       & foobaz\tnote{c}
    \end{tabular}
    \par\medskip
    \footnoterule
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item [a] first note 
    \item [b] second note 
    \item [c] the third note
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: beautiful; thank you! I was not aware of either threeparttable or threeparttablex.