# Footnotes on the same line

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs

For documents with a lot of footnotes, particularly if some are short, it can be nice to have multiple on the same line, e.g.:

> 1. this is the first footnote 2. this is the second footnote 3. this
>      if the third footnote 4. finally, we begin to wrap around.

Rather than having it:

> 1. First footnote
> 2. Second footnote
> 3. Etc.

Is there a way to achieve this in LaTeX?

(This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/multiple-footnotes-in-minipage-how-to-typeset-as-paragraph) because I'm asking about regular full page environment.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `para` option of the [footmisc](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package (which was the starting point of the linked question) *is* suited for a *"regular full page environment"*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\textheight=100pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{And yet another footnote which (finally!) ends on a new line.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Do you know if there's any way to toggle this functionality on for just one page, but keep standard footnoting on others?

Comment: Would be nice if it worked in beamer...

Comment: This does not work inside minipages

Comment: @Shane, one thing I've found is that you can use para from footmisc, and then end your footnotetext with \\\ to force a line break. this has gaps compared to the normal behavior, though.