# How to break URLs when footnotes are on same line?

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, paragraphs, urls, footmisc

Question [Footnotes on the same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line) revealed that it is a good idea to use `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`. However, this does not seem to work with URLs:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document} 
test\footnote{\url{http://www.example.org/long-URL/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long}}
\end{document}
```

[image: undesired result]

The given URL is **not** wrapped (but footnote 2 and 3 are on the same line). If footmisc is not loaded, the URL is wrapped perfectly. What can I do if I want to use footnotes with URLs next to each other?

More complex example (following answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56706/9075):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\myurl#1{\setbox0\vbox{\hsize.5\maxdimen
\url{#1}\par
\global\setbox1\lastbox}\unhbox1 }

\begin{document} 

test\footnote{\myurl{http://www.example.org/long-URL/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long}}

ODE\footnote{\myurl{http://ode.apache.org/}}). 
SOAP/http\footnote{\myurl{http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/}} 
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image: unexpected result]

I'd like to have footnote 2 and 3 on the same line

Comment: Be sure to load `hyperref` **after** `footmisc`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it work with `para` automatically you need a modified version of `\url`

[image]

as noted in the comments, you the first version added parfillskip glue after each url which padded to the end of the line, This version removes that.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\myurl#1{\setbox0\vbox{\hsize.5\maxdimen
\url{#1}\par
\setbox0\lastbox
\global\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox0\unskip\unskip\unpenalty}}\unhbox1 }

\begin{document} 
test\footnote{\myurl{http://www.example.org/long-URL/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long}}

ODE\footnote{\myurl{http://ode.apache.org/}}). 
SOAP/http\footnote{\myurl{http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/}} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on all cases (see above)

Comment: code updated to remove skip after each url

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the space between the footnotes? For me, there seems to be much space before "2" and "3".

Comment: TeX doesn't "want" to put a lot of space there, but with the limited number of places it can break a URL it has to over-stretch the space between paras (and complain in the log about underful boxes) You can get a better stretcing and no warnings by adding `  \Urlmuskip = 0mu plus 2mu` which allows a bit of white space around `/` and other url break-able characters,

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `[para]` option for `footmisc`, every thing works smoothly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
test\footnote{\url{http://www.example.org/long-URL/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** If you want to keep the para option for footmisc, we can pass the option `[obeyspaces,spaces]` to url (loaded by `hyperref`) and *give a space where the line has to be broken.* Since there comes an option clash between footmisc, we pass it to the documentclass.

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces,spaces]{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
test\footnote{\url{http://www.example.org/long-URL/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/long/ long/long/long/long/long/long}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really want to have the [para] option in place: I want to save space in a paper.

Comment: @koppor: See the edit.