# How to concatenate a whole paper into one big line of text + footnotes

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, posters

I've helped my girlfriend typeset her Bachelor's degree paper with LaTeX. I'd like to create a single-page poster version of the whole text.

Cf. "All the World's a Page" posters, e.g. http://www.all-the-worlds-a-page.com/products/das-kapital

Specifically, I need to deal with concatenating all the things into one continuous line. There's only one figure, a small table. Bonus points for emedding the table, but I'd rather get rid of it and not worry about floating text around the table.

1. How can I remove the newline and spacing from paragraphs and replace it with the `§` glyph instead?  Although I'd have to do the same for the headings and normalize their font sizes, I could just as well remove the markup instead. So the body text will be just simple paragraphs.
2. How can I concatenate footnotes the same way, remove newlines that is? I use biblatex with the footnote-dw style.

**Update:** [footnotes are already solved via `footmisc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line?rq=1) it seems.

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166418/put-entire-thesis-on-one-a0-poster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the original document, remove the table, and increase the paper size so that every paragraph fits on a single line. Decrease the font size, if necessary.

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm, paperwidth=550cm, paperheight=550cm]{geometry}
```

Then, copy the content of the PDF file and paste it into a plain text file. Replace all line breaks by " § " using sed or perl. Pay attention to the newline character(s) used by your operating system and text editor.

Paste the text into a new LaTeX file's document body and set the poster size you need.

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm, a0paper]{geometry}
```

Done.

Comment: That's kind of what I ended up doing, only I did replace newlines in the source document and then removed duplicate §. It's clever to render the document with very wide paper first. Don't know if that's feasible when you use footnotes, though.