# How to make all \thanks footnotes single line?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, footer

I have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title}
\author{ABC\thanks{XYZ} \and DEF\thanks{UVW} \and GHI\thanks{KMN}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and this produces footnotes on top of each other, like

```
* XYZ
** UVW
*** KMN
```

However I am really struggling to find some extra space in my paper and I want to write all of them on a single line, together with their symbols:

```
* XYZ, ** UVW, *** KMN
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob would you care to write up an answer, please?

Comment: @Troy i found a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28737/124842