# Footnotes on the same line only for one page

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs

It is possible to get footnotes typeset as paragraph thanks to package `footmisc` loaded with the `para` option, as discussed in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line).

But this is set globally. I would like to typeset footnotes as paragraphs only for some pages in one document. How can I get this functionality?

Comment: IIRC, the difference has to do with vbox and  \unvbox vs. \hbox and \unhbox applied to \footins while adding another entry.

Answer (score 1):

The `footmisc` package rewrites the output routine to deal with the footnotes and it is not easy to change that on a per page basis.  On the other hand, the `memoir` class has similar styles available and this can be changed mid document.

Page 1 (page 3 is similar):

[image: Page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Page 2]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\textheight=100pt% just for the example

\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{And yet another footnote which (finally!) ends on
a new line.}

\clearpage
\paragraphfootnotes

Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{And yet another footnote which (finally!) ends on
a new line.}

\clearpage
\plainfootnotes

Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{And yet another footnote which (finally!) ends on
a new line.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be useful to be able to reproduce `memoir`'s `\paragraphfootnotes` and `\plainfootnotes` commands behavior in other classes.