# Footnotes written on the same line?

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I have a long text with a lot of very short footnotes in it.  There is an unfortunate amount of white space at the bottom of a lot of pages.  How can I get the footnotes to write to the same line and then wrap around?  This footnote code I have right now is there to force the footnotes to respect the bottom margin.  Anything else can go.  I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line) and it was not working for me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\footnotesep=2pt
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
{\setspace@singlespace}{0.1}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\count\footins = 1000
    
    
Words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words words words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words words.\footnote{Short footnote.}  Words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words words words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words\footnote{Short footnote.} words words words words words.\footnote{Short footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Above is the code to replicate the screenshot.  I actually have a lot of other stuff in my header.  Just in case some of it might interfere with a proposed solution, I am also including the full header which I editted out above:

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}


%%% FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\footnotesep=11pt
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
{\setspace@singlespace}{0.1}
{}{}
\makeatother

%%% ADD HYPERREF AFTER FOOTNOTES: FORMAT PROBLEM %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


%%% DEFINE SECTION TITLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesection.}{.1em}{}

%%% DEFINE BOX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newsavebox{\myboxbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{+b}
{\centering
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    % measure the text width
    \sbox{\myboxbox}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-24mm}#1\end{varwidth}}\vspace*{0.9em}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        breakable, 
        colback=cyan!5,
        width=\dimexpr\wd\myboxbox+8mm,
        top=1mm,
        bottom=3mm,
        %enhanced,
        pad at break=2mm
        ]
        \begin{singlespace}
            #1
        \end{singlespace}
    \end{tcolorbox} \vspace*{0.3em}
}{}



%%% DEFINE HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsc{MAGNIFICENT TITLE}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textsc{AWESOME NAME}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}



\begin{document}
%%% MAKE FOOTNOTES RESPECT BOTTOM MARGIN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\count\footins = 1000
```

Comment: Normally, `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` would do this for you.  But it does not appear to work well with `revtex4-2`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I linked to the other question with that solution but it does not work, as you say.

Comment: I reformatted for {article} instead of {revtex} and now it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...