# Run-in paragraph footnotes inside a minipage

Tags: minipage, manyfoot

To obtain run-in paragraph footnotes in a document, `manyfoot` works just fine, one just needs to use the `para` option. But `manyfoot` is not compatible with the `minipage` environment. In the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}

\begin{document}

Above minipage

\medskip

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnoteA{Bla bla bla bla.}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnoteA{Bla bla bla bla.}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{minipage}

\medskip

Below minipage

\end{document}
```

`minipage` footnotes are displayed at the bottom of the page, not at the bottom of the `minipage`.

[image]

Is there some way to obtain run-in paragraph footnotes inside a `minipage`?

(I know this question has already been asked, but [the answer David provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/multiple-footnotes-in-minipage-how-to-typeset-as-paragraph) in 2015 works only for uniformly short notes. In my case, they are of very variable length, sometimes a single word, sometimes many lines of text…)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \ifvoid\@mpfootins
     \setbox0\hbox{}%
    \else
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \setbox0\lastbox
    \unskip % remove baselineskip glue (it will be recalculated for new text)
    \fi
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \def\@currentcounter{mpfootnote}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \ifdim\wd0>\z@
        \noindent\unhbox0\unskip\unskip% remove old parfillskip
        \hspace{1em plus 5em}% or whatever
      \fi
        \@makefntext{%
        \ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \par
    \color@endgroup}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Above minipage

\medskip

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{word}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{Bla bla bla bla.}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{Fooo fooo fooo foo Bla bla bla bla.}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\footnote{Bla bla bla bla.}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{minipage}

\medskip

Below minipage

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is being unskipped here Dave? \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \setbox0\lastbox
    \unskip

Comment: @YiannisLazarides baselineskip glue, I added a comment to the code,

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your quick response