# Re-shaping ordinary footnotes inside minipages

Tags: footnotes, minipage

I am trying to customize the series of ordinary footnotes which go into minipages.
I would like:

- to arrange them in a line (id est "para")
- to eliminate the footrule

Just the ones in the minipages, not the other (arabic) series!

Thank you!

MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBOLO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}


\usepackage{wrapfig}                        % Per avere immagini immerse nel testo
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}                 % Per traslare sezioni di testo (utile per allineare alle minipage)

\usepackage{float}          % per posizionare le tabelle con H


\usepackage{verse}
\setlength{\vindent}{0pt}

    

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbf{Minipage}}\\[-1.2ex]
\hrulefill
\end{center}

\begin{verse}
\vspace{-1.8ex}
Here goes some text with a footnote\footnote{A note in the minipage} and another one\footnote{Another note in the minipage}
\bigskip
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{1.5ex}
\begin{adjustwidth}{5.1mm}{-5.1mm}
\begin{center}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbf{Just a verse}}\\[-1.2ex]
\hrulefill
\end{center}

\begin{verse}
\vspace{-1.8ex}
Here other text with an ordinary footnote\footnote{A note at the foot}
\end{verse}
\end{adjustwidth}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you redefine commands within an environment (e.g. `minipage`), the new definition is "forgotten" once you close the environment. So you could define an environment which makes a minipage and redefines the footnote macros you need to redefine (e.g. `\renewcommand{\footnoterule}`)

Comment: For the inline footnotes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679111/233251

Comment: Thx! I turned that code into a .sty and it did the job